#  Setting (Bound) Model Object Properties from View in EmberJS...Programmatically?

Tags: html, contenteditable, ember.js

QQ: How can I update an object's property to match the innerHtml of an element in a view when a button is clicked?

I am working on building a content editing interface using EmberJS and the HTML5 contenteditable attribute (via the [Hallo editor](https://github.com/bergie/hallo)). This means that valueBinding doesn't do the trick, since we're dealing with the actual page HTML, not input/textarea value attributes.  I've built a similar app in Backbone, which lacks dynamic bindings but allows you to set the model object as a property of the view.

What's the best way to get this working with EmberJS?  Should I set a property on the view to the entire model? Do I need to create some sort of innerHtml binding and view helper, modeled on valueBinding?

I've set up a fiddle with an example of what I'm trying to do (with basic jQuery handling of the contentEditable attribute, instead of hallo):

http://jsfiddle.net/W6gsW/2/

Thanks!

Comment: you will probably find your choice of frameworks is over complicating what you are trying to achieve. no offense intended to Ember.

Comment: Thanks for the perspective, @tnt. I'm actually building the same app in Backbone and Ember as a way of comparing the two.  Ember certainly seems to have a great deal more convenience functions, but for this aspect Backbone's minimalism seems like it may be a benefit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://jsfiddle.net/ud3323/nXCvq/

I did change a few things with how you defined the bindings in App.docView to make things cleaner. My solution does feel a litte hackish, but it works with 1 line of code per property.

Comment: thanks @ud3323. unfortunately that code doesn't seem to be working for me: if I edit the HTML then click "Save" the info observer doesn't fire, and the text for both HTML elements gets replaced with "Object text"!

Comment: Updated. Sorry I was kinda in a hurry... :)

Comment: Thanks @ud3323, that works perfectly.  To sum, it looks like the solution was to bind on the content object, not individual properties of it, and to use the setPath method in the view to set the property value on change. Rockin'!